# OpenCV VideoCapture with Java

Tags: java, opencv

I have been trying to get OpenCV to work with my webcam and although I can manage to do so in Python, I haven't been successful in doing so with Java. I have seen that Highgui is no longer supported, or split for Java? So in this case should I use JavaCV, as I can't seem to find any actual updated documentation any more on video capture with Java.

Thanks.

Comment: if you are using opencv3.0, the VideoCapture was moved to a new videoio module.

Comment: problem is i can't find any actual documentation on videoio for java. i've looked around a lot.